# Bootstrap static navbar force expand on small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Given this menu code from a boostrap template, I want each menu item to both stack and take up the full width when the screen size is detected to be small. Essentially, identical functionality to when the "triple bar" menu button is hit, except the user does not have to manually press it.

Thanks in advance.

```
  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I understand is you wanted to make all menu items visible by default without users having to click on triple line (hamburger) menu and all menu items should be stacked horizontally on smaller screen.

Your code above is fine. Just add a class `"in"` to the `navbar-collapse` div and all set.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/35gSz/

Comment: Make sure you have Bootstrap JS is included in the page.